# Steam Installation Failure Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, steam

I'll be honest, I don't know much about Linux; my friend who's been using it for years is teaching me, but we're both out of ideas now.

We "installed" Steam on both my Chromebook that has Ubuntu 16.04 on it and my Raspberry Pi which runs a form of Debian (which might have the same problem).

They both say that `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`, and `libc6:i386` are missing (packages needed to be installed) when we try to launch `steam` on them. We've attempted to run every command we've found and it didn't work. Every time it just says it can't be located. Any help would be appreciated.

Current Status

```
(xenial)tex@localhost:~$ uname -m; dpkg --print-architecture; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
aarch64
arm64
i386
```

My friend also says this might be helpful

```
(xenial)tex@localhost:~$ screenfetch -n
tex@localhost
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Kernel: aarch64 Linux 4.4.127-13890-g6c206f1711d4
Uptime: 10h 23m
Packages: 970
Shell: bash 4.3.48
Resolution: 1280x800
DE: XFCE
WM: Xfwm4
WM Theme: Default
Xfce-dusk [GTK2]

Icon Theme: elementary-xfce-dark
Font: Sans 10
CPU: ARMv8 rev 4 (v8l) @ 1.512GHz

RAM: 1859MiB / 3813MiB
```

[image: Current Status]

Comment: @Terrance I tried what you said and nothing actually happened when I did "sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386" it just went to the next line, I even uninstalled steam, did that command and reinstalled it and it says the same thing

Comment: yes I did, but still the same error when I try to run steam

Comment: Just ran that command and still it gives me that error, I don't understand my friend said he's never seen something like this before but I've seen exactly it in my only other experience with Linux

Comment: I know Multiverse is Enabled because I've run that one before, the other ones I don't know because another thing that surprised the both of us was that there was no software and updates tab in the settings

Comment: This better be ONLY Ubuntu that you are trying this in.  Software & Updates is ALWAYS there by default.  If it is not, I would suggest then that you reinstall your Ubuntu clean on the system.  I will not help with Debian as it is not refined like Ubuntu, and it is much more complicated to get things like Steam setup on it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/afA4c.png Here's a screenshot if you don't believe me, my friend told me it was Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You probably then need to reinstall your Software & Updates, `sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-gtk`  That application should be there all the time.  It might have been removed at one point.  Please reinstall it, then run `software-properties-gtk` and make sure that they are all enabled.  I am running out of ideas other than just short of telling you to clean install your OS.

Comment: If you need to actually discuss stuff like this with troubleshooting, it is best to ask questions like these at https://ubuntuforums.org/

Comment: They are all enabled, I ran a sudo apt update and tried launching it again, but still the same message, I'll go check if someone in on the forums know, but thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -m; dpkg --print-architecture; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` on both systems in question? I suspect that they’re not based on Intel processor architectures; the RasPi certainly is not and many Chromebooks aren’t either. Thanks.

Comment: Ran the uname and added its output also right now I just care about the chromebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the friend mentioned who has "Linux experience". I'm not an expert, I just enough knowledge to guide him.

I've already told him that an ARM version doesn't exist but I'm posting this so people get a clearer answer.

The issue is Valve *doesn't* have a build of Steam available for ARM from what I've read from people trying to install it on ARM computers. It's only available on x86_x64. And I feel like Valve won't ever since the Steam Link is a thing. [(src)](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4061)

For those looking for a way to stream (Steam or not) games to an ARM computer using Ubuntu/Debian should look at [Parsec](https://parsecgaming.com/downloads) or Limelight forks like [Moonlight](https://github.com/irtimmer/moonlight-embedded) (this requires an NVIDIA GPU on the host machine!)

For those looking to play Steam games on ARM devices looks like you're out of luck until Valve releases Steam for ARM.

Answer (score 1):

When I installed steam I had to install these packages using this command before installing steam

```
sudo apt install wget gdebi-core libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

but not libc6:i386, so that might be part of gdebi-core

This is the page I followed https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

I just checked my history, on one machine I followed the Ubuntu section of that guide, which does not install those libraries, on my other machine I followed the steam section which did install those libraries. Both systems are working fine, so either set of instructions should work for you.

Comment: I walked through the guide and tried the command you said after uninstalling steam and it still says there all missing

Comment: @TexasZeEdiot are you getting the error about the missing libraries when you install steam or when you run steam after installation? Are you getting an error when you try to install the libraries themselves? Add any output of the error to your question.

Comment: when I try to start up Steam/run it I says this "Steam needs to install these additional packages: *lists the ones previously mentioned*" it asks for my password so I can try to find them and then it says 
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: Unable to locate package libc6:i386"